# timed events to loop forever

Tags: javascript, events, timed

I have this code which is executed on page load:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function timedEvent1()
{
  setTimeout("ShowObjectWithEffect('wb_TextArt2', 1, 'dropup', 500)",0);
  setTimeout("ShowObjectWithEffect('wb_TextArt2', 0, 'dropdown', 500)",3000);
  setTimeout("ShowObjectWithEffect('wb_TextArt3', 1, 'dropup', 500)",3000);
  setTimeout("ShowObjectWithEffect('wb_TextArt3', 0, 'dropdown', 500)",6000);
  setTimeout("ShowObjectWithEffect('wb_TextArt4', 1, 'dropup', 500)",6000);
  setTimeout("ShowObjectWithEffect('wb_TextArt4', 0, 'dropdown', 500)",9000);
  setTimeout("ShowObjectWithEffect('wb_TextArt5', 1, 'dropup', 500)",9000);
  setTimeout("ShowObjectWithEffect('wb_TextArt5', 0, 'dropdown', 500)",12000);
  setTimeout("ShowObjectWithEffect('wb_TextArt6', 1, 'dropup', 500)",12000);
  setTimeout("ShowObjectWithEffect('wb_TextArt6', 0, 'dropdown', 500)",15000);
}
</script>
```

How can I loop this set of events forever? I read about the "setInterval" function but I cannot seem to implement it correctly in the above code.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
function timedEvent1() {
    setTimeout("ShowObjectWithEffect('wb_TextArt2', 1, 'dropup', 500)", 0);
    setTimeout("ShowObjectWithEffect('wb_TextArt2', 0, 'dropdown', 500)", 3000);
    setTimeout("ShowObjectWithEffect('wb_TextArt3', 1, 'dropup', 500)", 3000);
    setTimeout("ShowObjectWithEffect('wb_TextArt3', 0, 'dropdown', 500)", 6000);
    setTimeout("ShowObjectWithEffect('wb_TextArt4', 1, 'dropup', 500)", 6000);
    setTimeout("ShowObjectWithEffect('wb_TextArt4', 0, 'dropdown', 500)", 9000);
    setTimeout("ShowObjectWithEffect('wb_TextArt5', 1, 'dropup', 500)", 9000);
    setTimeout("ShowObjectWithEffect('wb_TextArt5', 0, 'dropdown', 500)", 12000);
    setTimeout("ShowObjectWithEffect('wb_TextArt6', 1, 'dropup', 500)", 12000);
    setTimeout("ShowObjectWithEffect('wb_TextArt6', 0, 'dropdown', 500)", 15000);
    setTimeout(timedEvent1, 18000);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot pete... your solution didn't cross my mind! Worked like a charm :)

Answer (score 0):

Put whatever it is you would like to do in a function, and then call the function with setInterval:

```
$(document).ready (
    timing = setInterval ( yourFunction , 900 ) ;
) ;
```

Oh, and to use that jquery function make sure you're loading jquery in your document

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Under the assumption that the third argument to the 'ShowObjectWithEffect' function is animation time in milliseconds, you could call timeEvent1 every 15500 seconds.

```
setInterval(function(){ timedEvent1(); }, 15500);
```

Comment: Hello Josh... I had this solution in hand but didn't know where to put it. Done by putting it before the </script> tag. Thanks a lot :)